# Sending POST data with Requests library in Python

Tags: python, html, post, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am unable to send POST data to access my account using requests library in Python. The resulting `soup` is the same as if no POST has been sent This is the code I have been using and worked on a different site:

```
def get_data(final_url):
    payload = {'session[email]':'myemail@myemail.com','session[password]':'mypwd','session[remember_me]':'0','commit':'Sign in'}
    with requests.session() as ses:
        log_soup = BeautifulSoup(ses.get('https://www.login-page.com/login').text)
        payload['utf8'] = log_soup.findAll('input',attrs={'name':'utf8'})[0].get('value')
        payload['authenticity_token'] = log_soup.findAll('input',attrs={'name':'authenticity_token'})[0].get('value')
        ses.post('https://www.login-page.com/login',data=payload)
        req = ses.get(final_url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)

    return soup


<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sign_in" class="main_form" id="new_session" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;"/><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="l5+2s90FtEUsS3GHlr2tAktcxSW8jqgXx3mXEwIlAzE="/></div><div class="error_message">
</div>
<dl>
<dt><label for="session_email">Email</label></dt>
<dd>
<div class="input_border"><input autofocus="autofocus" class="text required email" id="session_email" name="session[email]" placeholder="Email" size="30" type="email"/></div>
</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
<dt><label for="session_password">Password</label></dt>
<dd>
<div class="input_border"><input class="text required" id="session_password" name="session[password]" placeholder="Password" size="30" type="password"/></div>
</dd>
</dl>
<div class="checkbox_field"><input name="session[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0"/><input id="session_remember_me" name="session[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1"/><label for="session_remember_me">Remember me</label></div>
<table class="buttons">
<tr>
<td><input class="button public" data-disable-with="Please wait..." name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in"/></td>
<td class="forgot_password"><a href="/passwords/new">Forgot your password?</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The POST data obtained after manually logging in is the following:

```
utf8:✓
authenticity_token:l5+2s90FtEUsS3GHlr2tAktcxSW8jqgXx3mXEwIlAzE=
session[email]:myemail@myemail.com
session[password]:mypwd
session[remember_me]:0
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Does your login page expect JSON-encoded data, or form-encoded? Could it be that it's just not able to parse your posted data?

Comment: Yes I think it does, however, I added `json.dumps(payload)` to send as my data but still the form didn't get submitted.

Comment: The POST data from your manual logging -- where'd you get that? Any chance you could run the same request with wireshark? It _looks_ like you're invoking `requests` correctly, and so it would be nice to determine whether or not it's on the client or server side

Comment: I got it by recording the response following my POST request using Chrome developer tools. The resulting output is the same as if no POST was sent. What output from wireshark would you be looking for?

Comment: I'd just be curious to see that the HTTP request from `requests` is definitively a `POST` with the data. If we're sure of that, then we'd know it's the server. I would try to replicate a successful login with curl

Comment: So the curl in the form: `curl --data "utf8=✓&authenticity_token=l5+2s90FtEUsS3GHlr2tAktcxSW8jqgXx3mXEwIlAzE=&session[email]=myemail@myemail.com&session[password]=mypwd&session[remember_me]=0" https://www.login-page.com/login` redirected me to the website as it should do. I.e. I assume the `POST` was not sent properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of requests are you using? If it is anything between 0.14.x and 1.2.0 you must upgrade to 1.2.0. Cookies on the session won't be set properly on a redirect and 1.2.0 fixes this.

The other issue is that, you should probably be checking the response from `ses.post(url, data=payload)`. You should definitely check that you're receiving the proper status code (in this case, since you're expecting a redirect) something along the lines of a 301 or 302.

Assuming all of the above checks out, your website may be doing some funky `User-Agent` analysis and you may also want to check that with a browser user-agent string, e.g.,

```
ses.headers['User-Agent'] = '...'
response = ses.post(url, data=payload)
final_response = ses.get(final_url)
```

Comment: +1 for making me realize that my version is outdated and saving me a lot of grief for the future. Also I passed the header as you suggested with no obvious effect. The status code that I am receiving is 200 not 301 or 302 so I am assuming I am not passing POST data as I should be.

Comment: @Matt then check the response's history too for the redirect. Also, you can do the following: `ses.post(url, data=payload, allow_redirects=False)` that will give you the redirect response and tell you where you should be getting redirected to. It may also prevent the server from expiring your cookie if it determines you're scraping the site.

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the right path! You have been very helpful!